# Наследование TreeNode

Tags: c#, treeview

Хочу создать свою TreeNode - TreeINode. Наследую TreeNode в TreeINode. Вылазит ошибка:

> Ошибка CS7069 Ссылка на тип "MarshalByRefObject" требует его определения в "mscorlib", но его не удалось найти.

Нашел решение ошибки: добавить в ссылки System.Data.dll
Далее вылетает ошибка:

> Ошибка несоответствие между архитектурой процессора проекта "MSIL", сборка которого выполняется, и архитектурой процессора ссылки "System.Data", "AMD64". Это несоответствие может привести к ошибкам во время выполнения. Рекомендуется изменить целевую архитектуру процессора для проекта с помощью диспетчера конфигураций, чтобы согласовать архитектуры процессоров для проекта и ссылок, или использовать зависимость от ссылок с архитектурой процессора, соответствующей целевой архитектуре процессора проекта.

Целевые платформы:
.NET Framework 4.6
ASP.NET Core 1.0
Windows Universal 10.0
Сам проект - библиотека классов.

При наведение курсора на TreeNode вылазит окошко:

> Module 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' should be referenced

Comment: Выбрать сборку под вашу платформу? Выбрать версию фреймворка подходящую для текущей платформы? `should be referenced` - добавить ссылку на 'это' в проект.

Comment: А какой у вас тип проекта?

Comment: @VladD Не компетентен в этом вопросе, но попробую. Библиотека классов.

Comment: @NewView .NET Framework 4.0 Visual Studio не дает поставить и это вроде не резонно

Comment: Это почему же? Все версии NET включают в себя предыдущие версии, для обратной совместимости. Вам надо добавить ссылку на модуль реализации версии 4.6. По этому кстати NET такой 'толстый' :)

Comment: @NewView можно пожалуйста поподробнее или можете прикрепить ссылку

Comment: Что подробнее? Ещё раз посмотрите свойства проекта, выберете версию фреймворка 4.6 Client, и после этого почистите все ссылки внутри проекта и добавьте потом их заново но, предварительно сохранившись. Добавляя ссылки на сборки,  контролируйте их версию NET.

Comment: Если и это не поможет, рекомендую с нуля создать новый проект с учётом вышесказанного, ничего там не трогать в свойствах и перенести и добавить ваши файлы исходников. Потом сравнить настройки. Так же нужно проверить целевую платформу, недаром вам там про AMD процессор предупреждение (target). Всякие сторонние модули добавляйте через Nuget, он сам установит именно совместимые сборки по версии NET и целевой платформе.

Comment: @NewView Добавляю System.Windows.Forms версии 4.6.1 (сам проект 4.6). Та же ошибка. Придется пересоздавать проект.

Comment: В 4.6 кажется какая-то пляска с бубном с Windows.Forms,  ее поддержка весьма условна и базируется на бридже к прошлым версиям кажеться. И в библиотеке классов лучше не использовать ссылки на Windows.Forms, если конечно это не UserControl.

Comment: Ну как бы понятно: asp.net core подразумевает, что mscorlib в проекте нет. Если вам нужна UI-библиотека, то вам придётся указывать таргетом только .NET Framework по идее.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил путем создания проекта с нуля.